# Stop SQL default instance

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2014 named instance and configured to connect on static port 1433(Default SQL port).

For example:

```
db.mycompany.com\SQL2015,1433
```

But it's able to connect to the default instance without any port (the default instance, which I didn't install and which is not present in SQL Server configuration manager).

i.e. I am able to connect with this string:

```
db.mycompany.com
```

Can anyone help figure out this issue and stop the default instance?

Answer (score 1):

Issue the command:

```
print @@SERVERNAME
```

on both instances and compare the output.  It should be the same. SQL Server doesn't install a "default instance" without your permission.

If you didn't install a "default instance," SQL is helpfully pointing your connection request to db.mycompany.com\SQL2015,1433.  Because that's clearly what you meant.  ;)

Comment: Thanks !                                                                                                       I was using port 1433 in Named instance,which is the port for Default instance.That was the issue.